# String is not output correctly from pandas dataframe to .CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I am making new column with pandas from existing timestamp column

result:

```
timestamp
2019-11-27 00:00:14+00:00
```

```
result['Hour'] = result['timestamp'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[11:13])
print(result)
```

```
Hour
00
```

```
result.to_csv(f"{date_now} - Database Export.csv",
              encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

```
Hour
0
9
...
12
13
14
```

If hour is in range of 00 - 09 my .csv file has hour column with only 1 number - 9 instead of 09 and 0 instead of 00.

Any ideas why?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is not with the file but with the Numbers app in MacBook, when I opened the same file in LibreOffice or Excel the hours are shown correctly. Numbers omit the first zero for some reason.